# Can't find module @angular-mf/core while creating example with Angular Micro Frontend Using Single SPA framework

Tags: angular, micro-frontend

Error: src/app/attack/attack.component.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular-mf/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { CoreService } from '@angular-mf/core';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/result/result.component.ts:2:24 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular-mf/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { Attack } from '@angular-mf/core';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/app.module.ts:5:28 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular-mf/core' or its corresponding type declarations.

5 import { CoreModule } from '@angular-mf/core';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error: src/app/app.module.ts(24,5): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
Could not resolve @angular-mf/core relative to [object Object].

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your project can't find the @angular-mf/core utility, try one (or more of the following):

1. If you already find the package exposing `@angular-mf/core` in the `package.json`-file, try running `npm install`
2. If not finding it in `package.json`, try installing it (`npm install <package-name>`) - I can't seem to find the package on npmjs.com, so I can't tell you what package you need to install.